# Change the down state color of the Android ActionBar UP/Home button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ABS, and I basically just want to know if there is any property that will let me overide the default blue I'm getting in a button down. My application is all red, and it's a small detail that's killin me. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `actionBarItemBackground` theme attribute will allow you to change the action item selector.

If you're using it with ActionBarSherlock be sure to provide an entry with and without the `android:` prefix.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to toggle it when hit down?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The supplied drawable should be a [state-list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) which handles the different states.

Comment: Gotcha. It seems that it was me that wasn't sure what you mean. Heh. Thanks again